# What part of the headlight is this called?

Tags: ford, headlight, lights

[image: image of right light bulb]

Hi there.

There is a light bulb in the very top right hand corner of this light and I dont know what it would be called as it isn't classed as a headlight

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Running light, side light, or accent light.

Comment: Also "park light"