# How to remove accent/side light on Ford Focus mk2 headlight unit

Tags: ford, headlight

Need to know how to remove the side running light on the headlight unit, located in the top corner of the unit on a ford focus mk2.5

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there any way you can take a picture of exactly which light you're talking about and post it?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it’s probably this one shown in this post : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/65368/10976